# Symfony - Getting the controller action path in a controller that renders a modal twig.

Tags: forms, symfony, routes, modal-dialog, action

If you are grabbing the route path (i.e.  /employees/edit/5) inside a controller that renders a modal div, you can't use $request->getPathInfo() in setting the modal's form's target/action, because the controller hasn't been called yet and therefore $request->getPathInfo() inside the controller will only return "_fragment", which is perfectly understandable.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I suppose you could inject the request stack into your controller and grab the original master request from it.  Kind of surprised the sub-request your controller receives does not have the information.  It's basically a clone of the original master request.

Comment: I know, it is surprising.

Answer (score 0):

I think you call your controller with

```
{{ render(controller(' ... ')) }}
```

There is no HTTP Request, just a function call in your Controller :)

If you want, you can get MasterRequest in your controller :

```
dump($this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest());
```

Comment: Right.  So if there is no HTTP request then you can't grab any route/action information from a request object.

Comment: Hi P., the getPathInfo() for the master request returns the "parent action" information, I need the action for the child modal form controller action.

Comment: @BrentHeigold Can you give an example of a "child modal form controller action"?